# Sub-packaging my static meta-model classes on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, eclipse-indigo, annotation-processing

I'm currently using Eclipse Indigo and I'd like to have my meta-model classes to be automatically generated in a sub-package instead of having them in the same package of my entities.

I've followed the instructions in the [JPA User Guide for Canonical Model Generator](http://wiki.eclipse.org/UserGuide/JPA/Using_the_Canonical_Model_Generator_%28ELUG%29) on Eclipse Galileo, but it's not working at all with Indigo. :(

Does anybody use the static meta-model classes in a sub-package? Is there any way to configure it on Eclipse Indigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe you should not change package**
I would suggest against it, because having those in sub package (or any other) violates current JPA 2 specification:

> • For each managed class X in package p, a metamodel class X_ in
>   package p is created.[67]
>   ...
>   [67] We expect that the option of
>   different packages will be provided in a future release of this
>   specification.
>   ...
>   Implementations of this specification are not
>   required to support the use of non-canonical metamodel classes.
>   Applications that use non-canonical metamodel classes will not be
>   portable.

Other way to organize is common JUnit practice: same package in different source directory.

**But if you have to, this is how it is done**

Following works at least with Eclipse version: Indigo Service Release 1 20110916-0149 and EclipseLink: eclipselink-2.3.0.v20110604-r9504. Names of the JARs can slightly vary from version to another.

If enabled, disable generating to the same package where entities are:

1. Go to Project Properties - JPA and check that value of Source Folder
   is `<None>`

Adjusting generating to the other package:

1. Properties - Annotation  Processing
   [x] Enable project specific settings
   [x] Enable annotation processing
   [x] Enable processing in editor
   Generated source directory: src (or wherever sources live)
2. New processor option:
   key=*eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage*
       value=*sub* | (desired package name)
3. Go one level deeper to the Annotation Processing | Factory Path and select Add External JARs and add following jars:
   eclipselink/jlib/jpajavax.persistence_2.0.3.v201010191057.jar
   eclipselink/jlib/jpaeclipselink-jpa-modelgen_2.3.0.v20110604-r9504.jar
   eclipselink/jlib/eclipselink.jar
4. Let Eclipse rebuild project.

Comment: Just for a matter of organization. I think it doesn't necessarily "violates", what the specification says is that it's not yet supported by the specification itself, what doesn't mean that implementations will not support it. EclipseLink had support for subpackaging my static canonical metamodel on Galileo, I just don't know how to use it on Indigo. I still want to use a static canonical metamodel, by the way. Non-canonical means that the application would be responsible for generating the metamodel classes, and, then yes, it violates the specification and that's not what I want.

Comment: Then we have very different view. I think it does. Specification does not specify tools. It defines outcome. Outcome can be obtained by some tool or by just creating files by yourself. Tool that provides possibility to generate metamodel to other package does not violate specification. Result of using such a option produces something that violates specification (in this case stuff in wrong package). Anyway, I will describe how to do it by editing answer.

Comment: I followed these instructions, but still it doesn't do anything. My metamodel classes are still being created in the same package of my entities. My view comes from [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/), where it says that sub-packaging, versioning, and naming conventions are still a concern for the specification that is not yet clear enough, and, thus, it's not wrong to have your own approach about it. In my case, I want a different sub-package and I don't want it to be in my SCM.

Comment: Hehe! Yes, that's odd! I did exactly what you recommended before posting this question. And I'm using the same version you mentioned: EclipseLink 2.3. In the JPA UserGuide I mentioned they're using a JPA 2.0_preview with EclipseLink 1.2. Maybe that's the problem. Or the support for those processor options was removed, or the option keys maybe have changed.

Comment: Tried it once more and recorded every step (updated to answer), want to give it one more try? I don't think versions in guide are problem, because for me this works. About article, what it comes to names and packages, for me specification is clear enough. Some day we will maybe have some other specification, but until then I try to live with this one. Until that locating files to freely chosen packaging means that result maybe works (or maybe not) with other providers.

Comment: Ahh!! Just reviewed my project settings and I had previously selected the canonical metamodel source folder in JPA settings! I set now to <None> and it works! Thanks for your help, man! Appreciate a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, article you linked is published before final 2.0 specification came out, thats why it maybe tells that something is not yet clearly specified.

Comment: As of **2019** the latest, JPA 2.2 specification still requires to have your metamodel classes in the same package as your entities. 
Page 238, §6.2.1.1 Canonical Metamodel. Link:

https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf